# Who claimed Alexander had a hairy heart?

Tags: sources, literature, death, alexander-the-great

From Avellaneda's *Continuation of Don Quixote*, [chapter 6, p. 34](https://archive.org/details/acontinuationhi01saavgoog/page/n34/mode/1up) (circa 1614, translated by Yardley 1784 apparently after the French of Le Sage 1705 but it all seems very confusing). Don Quixote says:

> [...] you should see your undaunted master deliver himself up to the most dreadful dangers with such resolution, that you could not but compare him to **Alexander the Great!** And you would be in the right for so doing: for I will lay a wager, and it is past all dispute, that if my breast were opened, my **heart would be found hairy,** as was that valiant king's.

Apparently there was a meme that Alexander's heart was found to have hair on it? I'm not familiar with this story. Can anyone track down a source for it, or any other references to it? Or know which figure Quifauxte was misremembering as Alexander here?

The closest Google gave me was [an 1878 curiosity about a woman killed by a hair growing into her heart](http://hauntedohiobooks.com/news/a-hair-in-the-heart/), which is not very close at all.

Comment: Possibly useful reference [dictionary.net](https://www.dictionary.net/hairy%20heart), "Pericarditis in which the heart is seen post mortem to be covered with a shaggy, fibrinous exudate; cor hirsutum, cor tomentosum, trichocardia, shaggy pericardium."

Comment: @MCW thank you! "Cor hirsutum" was indeed the key search term; I'll write up my findings in an answer.

Comment: Just for completeness, a link to the Spanish original: https://books.google.de/books?id=APgAAAAAMAAJ&pg=PA38.

Comment: [A medical journal article](https://www.ajconline.org/article/0002-9149(70)90701-0/pdf) discusses ancient references to heroes with hairy hearts going back at least as far as Homer,  but doesn't mention Alexander specifically.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to [MCW's comment above](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/74284/who-claimed-alexander-had-a-hairy-heart?noredirect=1#comment240389_74284): The Latin for "hairy heart" is "*cor hirsutum*," and it's the key to unlock the search results. TLDR: Quifauxte is confusing Alexander with either **Aristomenes of Messene,** or possibly **Alexander's dog.**

The first step for me was [this result](https://discovery.ucl.ac.uk/id/eprint/10062805/1/Aristeides%20BNJ%20286.pdf), which seems to be the "Aristeides of Miletos (FGH 286)" entry from [*Brill's New Jacoby*](https://scholarlyeditions.brill.com/library/urn:cts:greekLit:fgrh/) (2012). It's talking about a reference to Aristeides found in pseudo-Plutarch's [*Parallela minora* 306D](https://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Roman/Texts/Plutarch/Moralia/Parallela_Minora*.html#4.1):

> [Leonidas] made his way up to Xerxes and snatched off his crown. When he was dead the barbarian king cut out his heart and **found it covered with hair.** So says Aristeides in the first​ book of his *Persian History*. [Loeb Library's footnote: "Cf. Stobaeus, *Florilegium* VII.65; Lydus, *De Mensibus* 167."]

(The original Jacoby is [here](https://archive.org/details/jacoby-die-fragmente/Jacoby%2C%20Die%20Fragmente%20der%20griechischen%20Historiker%201/FGrH%203A1/page/167/mode/1up).)

Now, *Brill's New Jacoby* has its own commentary (by Paola Ceccarelli); she points to David Ogden's [*Aristomenes of Messene*](https://archive.org/details/aristomenesofmes0000ogde/page/113/mode/1up) (2004), where we find a multi-page discussion of *cor hirsutum*.

Ogden first quotes Stephanus of Byzantium's [*Ethnica*](https://books.google.com/books?id=STg9Q4D2NvcC&pg=PA81#v=onepage&q&f=false):

> When [the Spartans] finally defeated [Aristomenes] in the Messenian wars, they cut him open [...] and they found his innards to be extraordinary and his heart to be shaggy (δασει̃αν), as Herodotus, Plutarch, and Rhianus say.

(Plutarch may have written a "Life of Aristomenes," but if so, this is the only trace of it. [Plutarch does say that Herodotus says](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:2008.01.0352:section=11) that the Spartans defeated Aristomenes, but it seems that [Herodotus didn't even say that](https://archive.org/details/moraliainfiftee15plut/page/85/mode/1up), let alone anything about a hairy heart.)

Also found in Pliny's [*Natural History* 11](https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.02.0137:book=11:chapter=70&highlight=aristomenes):

> Aristomenes, the Messenian [...] the Lacedæmonians opened his breast while he was still alive, and his heart was found covered with hair.

Ogden lists six other instances of *cor hirsutum*, the first five of which are plausibly linked to bravery, and/or perhaps wolf-likeness (the wolf being peculiarly relevant to Sparta):

- Heracles' companion Stichius of Aetolia, per Ptolemy Chennus (summarized by Photius in [*Bibliotheca* cod. 190](https://www.tertullian.org/fathers/photius_copyright/photius_05bibliotheca.htm#190));
- Leonidas, per above;
- Lysander, per Eustathius' commentary on the *Iliad* (1.189);
- an unnamed dog belonging to Alexander, per Eustathius again;
- a dog named Briareus belonging to one of the Ptolemies, per Ptolemy Chennus again;
- the rhetorician [Hermogenes of Tarsus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermogenes_of_Tarsus), per the *Suda* ([Greek](https://books.google.com/books?id=fupCAAAAcAAJ&pg=PA1445), [English](https://www.cs.uky.edu/%7Eraphael/sol/sol-cgi-bin/search.cgi?db=REAL&field=adlerhw_gr&searchstr=Epsilon,3046)).

(Ogden says that Malcolm Heath thinks Eustathius was simply mistaken in both cases: he wrote "Alexander's dog" when he meant Ptolemy's, and "Lysander" for Leonidas. Malcolm Heath (1998), "Hermogenes' biographers," *Eranos* 96.)

Ogden also points out that Homer's *Iliad* refers to both ["Patroclus, of the shaggy heart"](https://www.theoi.com/Text/HomerIliad16.html) (Book 16) and ["Pylaemenes of the shaggy heart"](https://www.theoi.com/Text/HomerIliad2.html) (Book 2), using shagginess-of-heart as a metaphor for sturdy bravery.

So, in conclusion: Various Greeks have been described as "shaggy-hearted," as far back as Homer in the metaphorical sense, and then later in the literal sense. But Alexander the Great was never one of them.

---

In the context of Avellaneda's *Quixote*, this might be a true mistake by the author; but it could also be the character of Quixote making the malapropism (similar to how the true Quixote refers to "Perseus's thread" in Book 1); or it could even be a deliberate "slip" by the author in character as a writer of medieval romance (similar to how Sancho's donkey gradually reappears after being stolen). See Tom Lathrop (2010), ["*Don Quixote* and its Errant Author,"](https://www.jstor.org/stable/27920393) *New England Review* 31:4.